# Named conditions that are the result of exposure to psychopathic behavior of another person?

Tags: diagnosis

Are there any recognized terms for conditions that stem from or are the result of exposure to  psychopathic behavior (by another person) that are distinct from those that might have predisposed the individual to it or made them more vulnerable to it?

In other words, something like a "post psychopath stress disorder"?

It would not have to be an official diagnosis, it's the only applicable tag I could find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Environmental psychological conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental_psychology) (conditions triggered by an event arising from another person's actions or other event external to the person) will have the same name irrespective of whether they might have been predisposed to it, more vulnerable to it, or neither.

The question is very broad as there are many different conditions which can arise, which actually can be any condition within the spectrum of environmental psychological disorders. There is no such disorder as "Post Psychopath Stress Disorder" but psychological conditions can include Post Traumatic Stress Disorder, Anxiety, and [Vicarious Trauma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicarious_traumatization).  There can be many others arising from the physical and/or mental actions of the psychopathic individual.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should have somehow included "...which *indicate* that the condition is a result of..." to the question or not, but your answer addresses this nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I hink there is not a term for such situation. comorbidity is the condition that one person has more than one psychological disorder diagnosis.  It might cover the condition but as far as I know, it doesn't talk about the relationship between more than one disorder. There might be many reasons for comorbidity, two disorders can as you said, lead to each other or have similar byological dispositions. most of people with psychological disorders have more than one diagnosis. There are many discussions about comorbidity and it's implications on effectiveness of our diagnostic tools. for reference, I found this article by Kendall and Clarkin(1992): 
Kendall, P. C., & Clarkin, J. F. (1992). Introduction to special section: Comorbidity and treatment implications. Journal of Consulting and Clinical Psychology, 60(6), 833.
If you are talking about interacting with someone with a disorder, some behaviours such as violence by a person with a disorder can lead to PTSD but although I don't know it for sure, it won't be different from any PTSD?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you may have missed "result of exposure to psychopathic behavior (*by another*) " in the question.

Comment: [Comorbidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comorbidity) refers to the presence of one or more additional diseases or disorders co-occurring with a primary disease or disorder within the one individual.  Not between 2 or more people.

Comment: Although at a glance accurate, I am not sure this answer is relevant to the OP?

Comment: I thought by an other He/she meant an other disorder. Thus I said that one disorder can lead to other disorders.

Comment: I see what you mean. I've added the word "person" in both places to make it clearer, thanks for pointing out the ambiguity. It's completely optional, but if you now feel that this answer doesn't address the question, you could consider revising or even deleting it. There's no penalty for deleting and you can undelete later (nothing is ever 100% deleted in SE, things just become less visible to newer users) Welcome to Stack Exchange!